# Sharepoint 2013 Online - Display currentUser information in page

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I need to get the currentUser information, like email address and or name when a Home.aspx page is loaded in a specific area on the page like maybe the footer area. I have search and every JavaScript that I have found do not work. 
I need the text to display either in a Script Editor or Content Editor or an XML file.

What is wrong with the following JavaScript that I found. I have it in the WebApp Script Editor:

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init,”sp.js”);
var currentUser;
 function init(){
  this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  this.oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
  currentUser = this.oWeb.get_currentUser();
  this.clientContext.load(currentUser);
  this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQueryFailed));
 }

function onQuerySucceeded() {
  document.getElementById(“logUser”).innerHTML = currentUser.get_loginName(); 
 }

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
  alert(‘Request failed. \nError: ‘ + args.get_message() + ‘\nStackTrace: ‘ + args.get_stackTrace());
 }
< /script>
< div>Current Logged User:<label id=”logUser”></label></div>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please clarify your question? Also, smart quotes in text?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably `init` method is not executed since [SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff411788%28v=office.14%29.aspx) expects SharePoint Client Library `sp.js` to be loaded first. 
Use [SP.SOD.executeFunc method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff409592%28v=office.14%29.aspx) instead since it supports *on demand* scripts.

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext',function(){  
  var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var web = context.get_web();
  var currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
  context.load(currentUser);
  context.executeQueryAsync(
  function(){
      console.log(currentUser.get_loginName()); 
  }, 
  function(sender, args){
      console.log('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
  });
});
```